# clang++ (version 5) and LNK4217 warning

Tags: linker, compiler-warnings, clang++

I am just learning how to code.

I have installed clang version 5 on a windows 10 system using visual studio 14.

I created a hello world cpp file to test that is working.

Sample code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    int rip{1};
    int dal{4};

    int kane = rip + dal;

    cout << kane;
    return 0;
}
```

command

```
clang++ -o .\bin\testing.exe test.cpp
```

Clang does compile and I get an executable which does run as expected. however I do receive this message.

```
    test-3e53b3.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ___std_terminate imported in function "int `public: __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry(void)'::`1'::dtor$5" (?dtor$5@?0???1sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ@4HA)
test-3e53b3.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __CxxThrowException@8 imported in function "public: void __thiscall std::ios_base::clear(int,bool)" (?clear@ios_base@std@@QAEXH_N@Z)
```

I have searched online and can find similar issues but they are not the same.

I realise this maybe simple to you guys, but I am at a loss I have used various IDES and GCC and this code has not produced this warning before.

Answer (score 34):

Add **-Xclang -flto-visibility-public-std** to your compiler options.

Like so:

`clang++ -Xclang -flto-visibility-public-std -o test.exe test.cpp`

Edit:

Or use **clang-cl** instead:

`clang-cl -o test.exe test.cpp`

Comment: Works, but why? What is clang-cl and what does the option do?

Comment: `clang-cl` is the frontend that uses MSVC cl-like arguments, so e.g. `/std:c++17` instead of `-std=c++17`

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, this may or may not be the right solution.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57788067/2659307) for more details and options.